# Создаю куки, а их не видно (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, cookie, chrome-extension

Создаю куки в расширении хром с помощью **chrome.cookies.set**. Захожу на сайт site.com и там установлены мои куки. Всё хорошо. С помощью **chrome.cookies.get** вижу свои куки, а вот с помощью **chrome.cookies.getAll** не вижу. Выводит 200 куков и там нет моих с сайта site.com

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы мои куки отображались в **chrome.cookies.getAll**?

```
chrome.cookies.set({
    'url':'https://site.com/',
    'name':'test',
    'value':'ok',
    'expirationDate': parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000)+60*60*24
});
```

```
chrome.cookies.get({'url':'https://site.com/', 'name':'test'})
```

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({})
```

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({'url':'https://site.com/'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у Вас chrome.cookies.set работает, значит установлено

```
"permissions": [
      ...
       "cookies",
       "tabs"
     ],
"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
```

Такой вариант:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({
    }, function (сookies) {
        loCookies = сookies;
        console.log(loCookies);
    });
```

Comment: Прописал  "host_permissions": ["*://site.com/*"] и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою задачу.

Вся проблема была в том, что я выставил разрешение в манифесте `"host_permissions": ["https://site.com/*"]`, а на локальном сервере у сайта нет сертификата, поэтому куки искались по адресу http://site.com/.

Прописал `"host_permissions": ["*://site.com/*"]` или `"host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` и всё заработало.